# Why subtract $\pi$ in the definition of atan2?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, angle

Looking [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2#Definition) the definition of the `atan2` function is as follows:

$$\operatorname {atan2} (y,x)={
\begin{cases}
\arctan(\frac {y}{x}) & \text{if }x>0,\\
\arctan(\frac {y}{x})+\pi & \text{if }x<0\text{ and }y\geq 0,\\
\arctan(\frac {y}{x})-\pi & \text{if }x<0\text{ and }y<0,\\
+\frac {\pi}{2} & \text{if }x=0\text{ and }y>0,\\
-\frac {\pi }{2} & \text{if }x=0\text{ and}y<0,\\
\text{undefined} & \text{if }x=0\text{ and }y=0.
\end{cases}}$$

This looks wrong to me. Or at least, not wrong but rather there seems to be a small issue with it.

**My Reasoning**

I was trying to figure out a function (like $atan2$) that would solve the problem of the $arctan$ function. This is because I am writing a Python function to find the complex argument of a complex number, given real and imaginary part. Here is my reasoning:

Given a non-negative tangent value, this is mapped by the arctan only in the range $\left[0, \frac{\pi}{2}\right)$.

Given a non-positive tangent value, this is mapped by the arctan only in the range $\left[0, -\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$.

However, given a non-negative tangent value, there are two angles that could have that tangent value:

- $\arctan(\tan(\theta))$ which is an angle $\theta \in \left[0, \frac{\pi}{2}\right)$
- $\theta + \pi$ which is a diametrically opposite angle in the third quadrant, that is $\left[\pi, -\frac{3\pi}{2}\right)$

Similarly, given a non-positive tangent value, there are two angles that could have that tangent value:

- $\arctan(\tan(\theta))$ which is a negative angle in $\theta \in\left[0, -\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$
- $\theta + \pi$ which is diametrically opposite angle in the second quadrant, that is $\left(\frac{\pi}{2}, \pi\right]$

Thus, the definition of $atan2$ that I would use, would be:

$
\operatorname {atan2} (y,x)={
\begin{cases}
\arctan(\frac {y}{x}) & \text{if }x>0,\\
\arctan(\frac {y}{x})+\pi & \text{if }x<0,\\
+\frac {\pi}{2} & \text{if }x=0\text{ and }y>0,\\
-\frac {\pi }{2} & \text{if }x=0\text{ and }y<0,\\
\text{undefined} & \text{if }x=0\text{ and }y=0.
\end{cases}
}
$

Why does the Wikipedia definition subtract $\pi$ when we are in the third quadrant ($x<0$ and $y<0$)? If we do this, we end up with a negative angle! Yes sure, the negative angle would have the same sine, cosine and tangent of the angle obtained by summing $\pi$, but why bother?

Comment: You said it, why bother ?

Comment: Because in my way the definition is much more succinct, and I do not have to re-convert the angle at the end

Comment: You reconvert the angle because you want to adopt a different convention, you can only blame yourself. The "standard" convention is not worse than another.

Comment: The principal branch has $-\pi < \arctan2(x)\le \pi$.  Your definition doesn't satisfy that condition.

Comment: @MarkViola That! That is what explains everything! The principal branch of the complex number is defined within that interval because otherwise we could have multiple ones just by adding $2\pi$ multiples! Could you please write an answer for future reference?

Comment: "otherwise we could have multiple ones just by adding $2\pi$ multiples": what ??

Comment: The argument of a complex number is not unique, that is because we can just take any argument of a complex number, add a multiple of $2\pi$ to it and get an equally suitable argument. Instead, the principal argument is unique because it is restricted between $(-\pi, \pi]$

Comment: @Euler_Salter: the principal argument can also be defined to be in $[0,2\pi)$ or other. This choice is arbitrary and this has nothing to do with multiplicity.

Comment: The range that you choose, I agree, has nothing to do with multiplicity. However, the fact that you CAN choose a different range and keep sine, cosine and tangent the same, that is exactly because of multiplicity

Comment: @Euler_Salter The fact that we can choose a different range is do to periodicity of the functions.

Comment: The reason for using this definition with complex numbers is that the discontinuity occurs on the negative real axis. If you use $[0,2\pi)$ as the range, then the discontinuity is at the positive real axis. Given our general preference to set things around the positive real axis when possible, it makes sense to have the discontinuity on the negative axis instead.

Comment: The handy thing about atan2 as defined above is that if $(x,y)$ are the Cartesian coordinates of a point and $(\rho, \theta)$ are its polar coordinates, then $\theta = atan2(y,x)$.  (For simplicity, I'm disregarding the fact that multiple choices of $\theta$ are possible.)  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system

Comment: The proposed definition at the end of the question can produce every number in the range $[-\pi/2,3\pi/2)$ and no others. The output of the function is the same as the standard definition except when $x<0$ and $y<0,$ where it gives the usual result plus $2\pi,$ that is, an equivalent angle. It corresponds to a branch cut along the negative imaginary axis rather than the negative real axis. I think the reason for the standard definition is that applications that want output in $(-\pi,\pi)$ are much more common. Also I doubt typical software implementations actually compute the arctan first.

Answer (score 3):

For consistency, the $\text{atan}_2$ values are defined in a range that equals a full period.

The usual choice is $(-\pi,\pi]$, but this is arbitrary and inessential, provided you know it.

What really matters is that when taking the cosine and sine, the original signs are restored.

---

Whatever the convention, computing with angles is often tricky.